# Saving and Editing JSON on iPhone/iPod

Tags: iphone, json

What's the best method for editing and saving a JSON file on the iPhone/iPod? I know there are libraries that allow you to easily read JSON data, but are there any that allow you to generate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TouchJSON](http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/wiki/TouchJSON) reads and generates JSON, is quite fast, and uses very little memory.

[JSON Framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/) is supposedly faster, but uses much more memory.

The iPhone also includes a [built-in JSON parser/generator](http://samsoff.es/post/parsing-json-with-the-iphones-private-json-framework/), but it's only available through private APIs. You probably shouldn't use this one.

Answer (score 0):

**[TouchJSON](http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/wiki/TouchJSON)** allows conversion both to and from JSON with a single call like:

`[[CJSONSerializer serializer] serializeObject:someDictionaryofYours];`